# main: src/unix/core.c:117: uv_close: Assertion `!uv__is_closing(handle)' failed

Tags: c++, tcp, libuv

When I try to use the function `uv_close((uv_handle_t*)client,NULL)` in `libuv` library to actively close the TCP connection with the client, the error

> "main: src/unix/core.c:117: uv_close: Assertion `!uv__is_closing(handle)' failed."

was reported. I search a lot online, but I still cannot find the correct way to solve the problem. I wish someone can tell me why this problem resulted and how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with libuv, but try checking if the handle is being closed already before calling uv_close.  I think I see where the assertion is in the source code on github.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to close a handle that is either already closed or in a closing state (that is, somewhere along the process that brings the handle from being alive to being closed).

As you can see from the code of `libuv`, the `uv_close` function starts as:

```
void uv_close(uv_handle_t* handle, uv_close_cb close_cb) {
  assert(!uv__is_closing(handle));

  handle->flags |= UV_CLOSING;

  // ...
```

Where `uv__is_closing` is defined as:

```
#define uv__is_closing(h)                                                     \
  (((h)->flags & (UV_CLOSING |  UV_CLOSED)) != 0)
```

To sum up, as soon as `uv_close` is invoked on a handle, the `UV_CLOSING` flag is set and it's checked on subsequent calls to avoid multiple runs of the close function. In other terms, you can *close* a handle only once.

The error comes out because you are probably invoking `uv_close` more than once for a handle. However, it's hard to say without looking at the real code.

As a side note, you can use `uv_is_closing` to test your handle if you are in doubt. It's a kind of alias for `uv__is_closing`.